# Block domain for a specific app

Tags: firewall, hosts

Is it possible to Block domain for a specific app, like to edit host file or via firewall app (have root) to block domain but just to 1 or 2 app?

Comment: Hosts file is always globally active for all apps. A local VPN based blocker might work. I have read that e.g. Blokada allows to apply blocking only on certain apps user has selected from a list of installed apps.

Comment: Ty robert that works grate!